# In R, how can I tell if the scales on a ggplot object are log or linear?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have many ggplot objects where I wish to print some text (varies from plot to plot) in the same relative position on each plot, regardless of scale.  What I have come up with to make it simple is to

1. define a rescale function (call it sx) to take the relative position I want and return that position on the plot's x axis.

```
sx <- function(pct, range=xr){
    position <- range[1] + pct*(range[2]-range[1])
    }
```

2. make the plot without the text (call it `plt`)
3. Use the `ggplot_build` function to find the x scale's range

```
xr <- ggplot_build(plt)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.range
```

4. Then add the text to the plot

```
plt <- plt + annotate("text", x=sx(0.95), ....)
```

This works well for me, though I'm sure there are other solutions folks have derived.  I like the solution because I only need to add one step (step 3) to each plot.  And it's a simple modification to the annotate command (x goes to `sx(x)`).

If someone has a suggestion for a better method I'd like to hear about it.  There is one thing about my solution though that gives me a little trouble and I'm asking for a little help:

My problem is that I need a separate function for log scales, (call it `lx`).  It's a bit of a pain because every time I want to change the scale I need to modify the annotate commands (change `sx` to `lx`) and occasionally there are many.   This could easily be solved in the `sx` function if there was a way to tell what the type of scale was.  For instance, is there a parameter in ggplot_build objects that describe the log/lin nature of the scale?  That seems to be the best place to find it (that's where I'm pulling the scale's range) but I've looked and can not figure it out.  If there was, then I could add a command to step 3 above to define the scale type, and add a tag to the sx function in step 1.  That would save me some tedious work.

So, just to reiterate:  does anyone know how to tell the scaling (type of scale: log or linear) of a ggplot object?  such as using the ggplot_build command's object?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a list of pre-build plots:

```
linear <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point()

log <- linear + scale_y_log10()

linear <- ggplot_build(linear)
log <- ggplot_build(log)

plotlist <- list(a = linear, b = log)
```

We can grab information about their position scales in the following way:

```
out <- lapply(names(plotlist), function(i) {
  # Grab plot, panel parameters and scales
  plot <- plotlist[[i]]
  params <- plot$layout$panel_params[[1]]
  scales <- plot$plot$scales$scales

  # Only keep (continuous) position scales
  keep <- vapply(scales, function(x) {
    inherits(x, "ScaleContinuousPosition")
  }, logical(1))
  scales <- scales[keep]

  # Grab relevant transformations
  out <- lapply(scales, function(scale) {
    data.frame(position = scale$aesthetics[1],
               # And now for the actual question:
               transformation = scale$trans$name,
               plot = i)
  })
  out <- do.call(rbind, out)

  # Grab relevant ranges
  ranges <- params[paste0(out$position, ".range")]
  out$min <- sapply(ranges, `[`, 1)
  out$max <- sapply(ranges, `[`, 2)
  out
})
out <- do.call(rbind, out)
```

Which will give us:

```
out
```

```
  position transformation plot       min      max
1        x       identity    a 1.8800000 4.520000
2        y       identity    a 4.1200000 8.080000
3        y         log-10    b 0.6202605 0.910835
4        x       identity    b 1.8800000 4.520000
```

Or if you prefer a straightforward answer:

```
log$plot$scales$scales[[1]]$trans$name
```

```
[1] "log-10"
```

Comment: Thank you!  Just what I was looking for.